# Not sure how to call a class function using templates

Tags: c++, templates

I am making my own dictionary using templates **(no I can't and I won't use anything from STL)**.

I want to have a very simple search function, but I have a small problem.

```
template <typename TElement>
void Dictionary<TElement>::search(TElement ADT, int key) {  // Abstract Data Type
    inf flag = 0;
    index =  int (key % max);
    temp[index] = root[index]; // root of the hash
    while (temp[index]->next != NULL) {
        if(temp[index]->data->key_actual_name == key) { @things happen }
    }
}
```

**What I want to understand:** how to use template so that I can have `temp[index]->data-><template call>` if that makes any sense

I want to call the dictionary by using: Class_type == TElement and "key" is always an int but it can be different things. It might be an ID or phone number. Problem is I need to use the actual name of the key (`if(temp[index]->data->ID (or phone or what ever) == key`) { @things happen }), I imagine I could use templates here but I don't know how.

also maybe relevant:

```
template <typename TElement>
typedef struct list{
    TElement data;
    struct list *next;
}node_type;
node_type *ptr[max], *root[max], *temp[max];
```

Also, if I do use a template for key_actual_name, how would the implementation work AND how would I call that function ?

Comment: Flagged for rude and offensive, but I would appreciate anyone to explain what is wrong with that ? I'm willing to learn and understand if you're willing to explain instead of ... whatever @KerrekSB did.

Comment: Why or how is the keyword `typedef` used, please?  I have seen occasionally seen code that issues `typedef` like this, but I have admittedly never understood the purpose.  To me, `typedef` exists to define an alias for an existing type:  is that what your code does?

Comment: old borland c++ habit I think. Don't think I even understood why, but teacher insisted. Didn't realize it's not normal.

Comment: Well it looks a lot like C, or non-standard C++. I strongly suggest not to pickup that habit. In C++ just saying struct A { ... }; defines the type A, no need to prefix struct, no need for typedef, so why go through all the trouble ? :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get some inspiration  from standard library functions like `find_if` that has an extra parameter for the comparison.

```
template <class InputIterator, class Predicate>
InputIterator find_if ( InputIterator first, InputIterator last, Predicate pred );
```

You can then pass a parameter telling the `search` function how to find the key you are looking for. Perhaps replace the use of `==` with

```
if(pred(temp[index]->data, key)) { @things happen }
```

and pass different `pred` functions for comparing the key to the appropriate member.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am just a beginner and I don't follow. `pred(data, key)` ?. Also is there no way I could just use some sort of `template <typename getFunction>` then `temp[index]->getFunction == key` where I have either getNumber or getID and use it that way ?

Comment: +1 I was writing a answer suggesting to look at find_if implementation

Comment: have a look at this link http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/ there is an implementation of find_if

Comment: `pred` can be a function that compares `data->something` to `key`. Create one function for each comparison you need, and pass that to `search`. No template tricks needed. :-)

Comment: @Kalec pred is an unary template class that has an overloaded operator() with the following signature bool operator()(T& lhs, T& rhs) that will compare lhs with rhs and decide if they are equal.

Comment: It can *also* be an ordinary function `bool compare_x(TElement* data, int key) { return data->x == key; }`

Comment: true, I forgot about that case !

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly:

```
temp[index]->data->key_actual_name
```

resolves to a data member of TElement which is an int, and you want that to be a template.
If that's the case you can do this:

```
template <template <class> class TElement, typename TKey>
struct node_type
{
    TElement<TKey> data;
    node_type *next;
};

template <template <class> class TElement, typename TKey>
class Dictionary
{
    typedef node_type<TElement, TKey> node_t;
    node_t _root;

    void search(node_t& node, const TKey& key)
    {
        TKey& thekey = node.data.key_actual_name;
        // Do some algorithm
    }
public:
    void search(const TKey& key)
    {
        search(_root, key);
    }
};

template <class T>
struct Element
{
    T key_actual_name;
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    Dictionary<Element, int> dic1;
    dic1.search(1);

    Dictionary<Element, char> dic2;
    dic2.search('a');

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, the Element has a template parameter, so you can change the type of key_actual_name to whatever suits your case, yet have the search function access it in a generic way (assuming it has the operator== overload).

Comment: Yes, this is what I intended to say and I think this should work, thank you!. I will select your answer once I try this out.